# VS Code tab selects another button instead of adding a tab or 4 spaces to the code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The title explains it all, when I press tab while writing code, it selects the "Problems" tab instead of adding 4 spaces to my code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you've enabled accessibility mode with `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` command (`ctrl+m` by default).
Run this command again or click `Tab Moves Focus` on status bar:

[image]